# How can I access a remote URI using .NET core in a docker container?

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

I've been attempting to solve this one for far too long today and I haven't been able to find a workable solution anywhere.

I can't get my `XmlReader.Create(String uri, XmlReaderSettings settings)` (or `XDocument.Load(String uri)` ) to realise that I'm trying to use a path to a remote service.

The issue is very easy to reproduce (I hope):
Run a .NET Core 2.0 Console application that attempts to access:

```
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("file://magic.example.com/test.xml", xmlReaderSettings);
```

or

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("file://magic.example.com/test.xml");
```

Convert this to a docker project (Linux, not Windows), and run it.
The resulting error I find get is:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file '/app/\\magic.example.com\test.xml'.'
```

**The upsetting requirement**: My organisation uses windows-styled file sharing and we hope to keep this, I can fall back to FTP but this will bug me for a long time to come if I do.

---

Edit #1:

To get this working within my environment I've started using the NuGet package `SharpCifs.Std` which appears to be completely stable on both Windows and Linux. This isn't the 'ideal' solution for this question but it's working well. If I come across a non-package based solution for this I'll edit this post again.

Comment: LInux does not use paths like `\\magic.example.com`, so you can't use `file://` URLs. I'm not sure what is the correct replacement.

Comment: `file://magic.example.com/test.xml` should not be valid. `file://magic.example.com/path/test.xml` should be, corresponding to a UNC file path of `\\magic.example.com\path\test.xml`, which *should* open with .NET Core (using `File.OpenText`). You may need some custom code to handle these URIs specially. Another thing to try for Linux specifically is `smb://` instead of `file://`, though I don't know if .NET Core has any support for that.

Comment: Good suggestion @JeroenMostert, sadly smb:// returns `System.NotSupportedException: 'The URI prefix is not recognized.'`

It may be time to accept that I have to use a third party library.